# FIND() formula to include "implicit intersection operator" change required

Tags: excel

Over the weekend, my work laptop did a restart and Microsoft gave me the perfect gift in Excel, it introduced the implicit intersection operator which has completely messed up my world, literally every formula has gone crazy.

I've checked every link I can and cannot work out how to correct even the most basic formula. I would like to ask about this one so I can at least make some progress forwards.

`=FIND('Value Definitions'!C3,'User Interface'!K:K)` was my formula that was worked forever.

The explanation of this formula is to flag all value definitions that have been used within text of all rows in the user interface column K.

When Excel asks me to correct the formula, it rewrites it as `=FIND('Value Definitions'!C3,@'User Interface'!K:K)`.
This results in **#VALUE** rather than a number of where the first occurrence was found. If I remove the @ then I get **#SPILL!**.

Just to reiterate the purpose of the formula, I identify which phrases exist in an interface that come from the value definitions worksheet, irrespective of the number value I get (character count of first occurence), I just want to identify that it exists at least once. Then I can use this flag to lookup all related value definitions to be included on the user interface.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: I found an alternative formula but, I shouldn't have to find alternatives to fix non-backwards compatible changes applied by Microsoft. The alternative is `=COUNTIF('User Interface'!I:I, "*"&'Value Mapping'!C3&"*")` which might be better in this instance but not every time, thanks

Comment: Use implicit intersection operator at the beginning of formula.  Try- `=@FIND('Value Definitions'!C3,'User Interface'!K:K)`

Comment: Thanks for this, I did try `=@FIND('Value Mapping'!C3,'Rule Parameters'!G:G)` (sheet names have changed since) but it still comes up with **#VALUE!**. Thanks, Matt